# How to send twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError directly without requesting

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, timeout

I have a database of thousands of `URL`s which I scrape using one Spider. For example 100 `URL`s can have the same domain:

```
http://notsame.com/1
http://notsame2.com/1
http://dom.com/1
http://dom.com/2
http://dom.com/3
...
```

The problem is that sometimes a webpage/domain returns nothing, so I'm getting `<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure:`. Which is the same for all `URL`s of the domain.

I would like to detect Timeout for example for 5 urls of the same domain and then if I'm sure that this Host has some problems, avoid to requesting this domain anymore and directly raise `<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure:`

Is it possible? If yes, how?

**EDIT:**

My idea (edited with rrschmidt's help):

```
class TimeoutProcessMiddleware:
     _timeouted_domains = set()

    def process_request(request,spider):
        domain = get_domain(request.url)
        if domain in _timeouted_domains:
            return twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError
        return request

    def process_response(request, exception, spider):
        # left out the code for counting timeouts for clarity
        if is_timeout_exception(exception):
            self._timeouted_domains.add(get_domain(request.url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are on the right track with your idea of building a `TimeoutProcessMiddleware`. To be more specific I would build this as a Downloader Middleware.

A Downloader Middleware can touch each outgoing Request as well as each incoming Response ... and ... it can also process each Exception that pops up while processing a request/response. Details: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html

So what I would do (in a untested gist, might need some finetuning):

```
class TimoutProcessMiddleware(scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware):
    _timeouted_domains = set()

    def process_request(request, spider):
        domain = get_domain(request.url)
        if domain in self._timeouted_domains:
            raise IgnoreRequest():

    def process_response(request, exception, spider):
        # left out the code for counting timeouts for clarity
        if is_timeout_exception(exception):
            self._timeouted_domains.add(get_domain(request.url))
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing. In def err(self), I process Timeouted urls so It would be more simple if I just force Timeout error instead of raising IgnoreRequest(). Is it possible? Can't I just raise twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError directly? I want to process all urls of timeouted domain as they was Timeouted.

Comment: I've edited my code using yours. What do you think about it?

Comment: Based on the documentation we have to raise `IgnoreRequest` in `process_request` ... you might try using `TimeoutError` but I don't know what will happen, then. Also as in my example the Middleware does the bookkeeping you might be able to avoid using the err callback in the spider.